# Returning multiple counts into one query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to return the count values into multiple columns (ORDERS_1990, ORDERS_1991) but I am receiving the error "missing keyword".

```
SELECT
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDERS WHERE (ODATE BETWEEN '01-JAN-90' AND '31-DEC-90')),
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDERS WHERE (ODATE BETWEEN '01-JAN-91' AND '31-DEC-91'))
INTO ORDERS_1990, ORDERS_1991
FROM ORDERS;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely getting the message because you're using `SELECT ... INTO ...` outside of a PLSQL block. If you just want to label the results, just name the subqueries normally;

```
SELECT
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDERS 
  WHERE (ODATE BETWEEN '01-JAN-90' AND '31-DEC-90')) ORDERS_1990,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDERS 
  WHERE (ODATE BETWEEN '01-JAN-91' AND '31-DEC-91')) ORDERS_1991
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ODATE BETWEEN '01-JAN-90' AND '31-DEC-90' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN ODATE BETWEEN '01-JAN-91' AND '31-DEC-91' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
INTO ORDERS_1991, ORDERS_1992
FROM ORDERS;
```

I'm not sure why you are getting a "missing keyword" error.  I would expect the error to be that you are returning too many rows.  I think the following should work (assuming you are in a PL/SQL block):

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDERS WHERE (ODATE BETWEEN '01-JAN-90' AND '31-DEC-90')),
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDERS WHERE (ODATE BETWEEN '01-JAN-91' AND '31-DEC-91'))
INTO ORDERS_1990, ORDERS_1991
FROM dual;
```